# Templated delegates

Tags: .net, generics, delegates, template-method-pattern

I have the following piece of code pattern:

```
void M1(string s, string v)
{
  try
  {
    // Do some work
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    // Encapsulate and rethrow exception
  }
}
```

The only difference is that the return type and the number and types of parameters to the methods can vary.

I want to create a generic / templated method that handles all of the code except for the "Do some work" part, how can it be achieved.

Comment: It might be obvious to some, but still you should add a tag for the target language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the Action

```
public static void Method(Action func)
{
    try
    {
        func();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Encapsulate and rethrow exception
        throw;
    }
}



public static void testCall()
{
    string hello = "Hello World";

    // Or any delgate
    Method(() => Console.WriteLine(hello));

    // Or 
    Method(() => AnotherTestMethod("Hello", "World"));

}

public static void AnotherTestMethod(string item1, string item2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Item1 = " + item1);
    Console.WriteLine("Item2 = " + item2);
}
```